# Can I use the circuit from an electric mosquito bat in a homemade 3'x3' panel?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, dc

**SUMMARY:**  I'd like to take the control circuit out of four electronic mosquito bats and use them on a homemade panel version of the same thing.  I know little about electronics, so my question is, will it work, or will I need a different circuit (and/or maybe larger batteries) to power something that large?  I know that DC loses voltage over distance.  FWIW, the well-reviewed mosquito bats output 3000-4000V, and discharge is limited to 9 mA, well below the danger threshold for human contact.

**GOAL:**  I want to reduce the local mosquito population because they terrorize my wife and she can't enjoy the yard with the dogs.  She has a sensitive allergy and gets 1.5" dark blue bruises when they bite her, plus itching.

**PLAN:**

1. Construct a four-wall, open-top cage, 3'x3'x3', with window screening
   on the inside.
2. Attach an electrified panel on the outside of each wall (i.e.,
   1.5" from the inside screening).  The spacing prevents accidental nuisance shocks from inside the cage.  The panels will be 2x2 wood
   framing, with horizontal wires (alternating positive/negative), 6.1
   wires per inch, using 16-gauge galvanized wire, with as many extra
   vertical 1x2 as necessary to keep the wires straight.
3. Attach 2" wooden spacers onto the outside of the panels, then
   install 1/2"-hole hardware cloth (wire mesh) to the spacers, to
   prevent accidental nuisance shocks from outside.
4. Connect each panel to a circuit removed from an electric mosquito bat.  Connect all four
   circuits to a momentary switch, so the panel can't accidentally be left on.  All panels will be activated simultaneously by the switch.

**NO ALTERNATIVES:**  Whenever someone posts a problem on the Internet, everyone always suggests going with some other plan rather than solving the actual problem posted, so let me try to pre-empt that:  I don't have a porch I can screen and that's irrelevant anyway because we want to enjoy the *yard*.  None of the mosquito repellant products available works very well (we've tried several) or is toxic.  Electric bats have several downsides, the biggest being that it's easy for mosquitos to bite her before she notices them.  You've also got to go at them one at a time, so it's inefficient.  Fans with screening to catch them are okay but the CO2 has to constantly be replaced and there's no audible feedback of mosquitos being eliminated, so it's less than ideal.

**PRE-EMPTING OTHER OBJECTIONS:**  We don't have to hope that mosquitos will fly into it; they always make a beeline straight for her.  Mosquitos never bite her above the waist so 3' high, with no roof, should be fine.  If it doesn't work I'll build a taller cage with a roof.

**Panel with alternating wires (6.1 wires per inch):**

```
+|-------------------
 | -------------------|-
 |------------------- |
 | -------------------|
 |------------------- |
 | -------------------|
 |------------------- |
 | -------------------|
 |                    |
 +                    -
```

Comment: As there is zero load on the HV generator, except when a mosquito is in contact, you probably don't need more that one HV source. Your main problem is likely to be keeping the electrode assembly insulated and out of contact with other objects. Incidentally, how does you wife get into and out of a 3' cube? - you may need a hinged panel, which will complicate things.

Comment: Normally, you can think of wood as an insulator.  Given the high voltage and low current, you'll need to look at wood as a resistor.  I would consider looking at plastic to carry the grid rather than wood.

Comment: It sounds like you are making an open-air prison cell.

Comment: The mosquito killer will "leak" a certain amount due to corona discharge and will thus create a bunch of unwanted and corrosive O3. Probably not a problem outside but it will draw more current than perhaps expected and will tend to destroy materials such as rubber that happen to be in the vicinity.

Comment: Yes, there will be a hinged panel.  It shouldn't complicate things. • I'll switch to plastic as an insulator. • Can the volume of O3 generated be calculated?  I know it's a pollutant and I'm looking into health effects.